# Timezone conversions for DateTime in Ruby 1.8.6

Tags: ruby, datetime, timezone, localtime

(Stuck in Ruby 1.8.6 land)

Until recently I was using Time to parse UTC dates and print them in a local timezone

```
dt = Time.parse("20111225080000Z")
puts dt.localtime
Sun Dec 25 21:00:00 +1300 2011
puts dt.zone
"New Zealand Daylight Time"
```

Unfortunately the limits 1901 and 2034 finally got in the way and so I tried to use `DateTime`

`dt = DateTime.parse(date)`

But I cant find an equivalent to `.localtime`

```
dt.timezone is of course +00:00
DateTime.now().zone is +13:00
```

I went to use that but realized if the date being converted was NOT in Daylight Time the answer would be wrong. Note the `Time` class gets it correct, and converts the time to the `localtime` (not a specific timezone or offset) - midwinter => Standard time.

```
dt = Time.parse("20110725080000Z")
puts dt.localtime
Sun Jul 25 21:00:00 +1200 2011
puts dt.zone
"New Zealand Standard Time"
```

For `DateTime` class, where is the equivalent of asking for my local time without specifying an exact (and possibly incorrect timezone)?